# How can I print a table with a boucle for?

Tags: java

```
 package aideRobotTurtle;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;


class classA{
public static char[][] plateau;
public static int[] position;
public static char direction;
boolean check = true;
}
public class Structure_de_donnees {
public static void initialisation() {
char[][] plateau = new char[11][11]; 
plateau[0][0] = '/';



for(int k = 2; k < 10; k++) {
    plateau[1][k] = '-';
}
for(int k = 2; k < 10; k++) {
    plateau[10][k] = '-';
}
for(int k = 2; k < 10; k++) {
    plateau[k][1] = '|';
}
for(int k = 2; k < 10; k++) {
    plateau[k][10] = '|';
}
plateau[1][1]='+';
plateau[10][1]='+';
plateau[10][10]='+';
plateau[1][10]='+';

public static void main(String[] args) {
initialisation();
for (int lig=0;lig<10;lig++) {
for (int col=0;col<10;col++) {
System.out.print(plateau[col][lig]);
}
System.out.println();
}
 boolean check = false;
}
}
```

When I want to run the code, there is a problem in the line with the code : 
System.out.println(plateau[col][lig] with the following message of error : 
plateau cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: The purpose of the code is to create a table with 8 lines and 8 columns, and a graphic frame.

Comment: You need to reference it like so: `ClassA.plateau` since you’re using it from a different class.

Answer (score -1):

You define a `plateau` array in the void `initialisation`, but it gets terminated after the method finishes executing. Simply define `plateau` outside of that method.

Also, your classA is irrelevant to this question.